# How to get post count of user using firestore in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have migrated user post, followers and following from from firebase to firestore. Now i have migrated post, followers and following and post, followers count too.

Here the code i have migrated from firebase to firestore.

```
 import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase
 import FirebaseFirestore

class FollowApi {


var REF_FOLLOWERS = Database.database().reference().child("followers")
var REF_FOLLOWING = Database.database().reference().child("following")
let db = Firestore.firestore()

func followAction(withUser id: String) {


    let docRef = db.collection("user-posts").document(id)

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")

            self.db.collection("feed").document(API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).setData([document.documentID: true])

        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }



   self.db.collection("followers").document(id).setData([API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid: true])
   self.db.collection("following").document(API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).updateData([id: true])

}

func unFollowAction(withUser id: String) {

    let docRef = db.collection("user-posts").document(id)

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")



 self.db.collection("feed").document(API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).delete()


        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }



    self.db.collection("followers").document(id).setData([API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid: NSNull()])
    self.db.collection("following").document(API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).setData([id: NSNull()])

 }

func isFollowing(userId: String, completed: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let docRef = db.collection("followers").document(userId)

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {

            print("documnetData::::\(String(describing: document.data()))")
            if let dataDescription = document.data(), let _ = dataDescription[API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid] as? Bool {

                completed(true)
            }

            completed(false)

        } else {
           completed(false)
        }
    }


}





    func fetchCountFollowing(userId: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
  //     REF_FOLLOWING.child(userId).observe(.value, with: {
  //                snapshot in
 //                let count = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
 //                completion(count)
 //            })



        db.collection("following").document(userId).getDocument { (querySnapshot, error) in

            let count = Int((querySnapshot?.documentID)!)
            print("followingCount::::\(String(describing: count))")
            completion(count!)
        }

    }

 }//followAPI
```

I tried to get following counts from firestore.

```
  let count = Int((querySnapshot?.documentID)!)
            print("followingCount::::\(String(describing: count))")
            completion(count!)
```

[image]

but does not show any any yet all. I do not know what mistake i have done ?

Any help much appreciated pls....

Comment: Is this you're looking for `let count = querySnapshot?.documents.count`?

Comment: @TheTiger yes exactly!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're querying for a `collection` then its `snapshot` will contain an array of `documents`. What are you trying to get is a `documentID` which is same as `key` in `Firebase`.

> **Firestore  | Firebase**
>
> documentID = snapshot.key
>
> documentData = snapshot.value

Now, Come to the main point and here is what you need to get the count.

```
let count = querySnapshot?.documents.count
print(count)
```

**EDIT For Comment:** *how can i migrate REF_FOLLOWING.child(userId).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in let count = Int(snapshot.childrenCount) completion(count) }) to firestore*

Based on attached DB structure you're fetching `following` corresponding to `userId` which is a `Document`.

```
REF_FOLLOWING.document(userId).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
    if let _error = error {
       print(_error.localizedDescription)
       return
    }

    guard let _snapshot = snapshot else {return}

    /// This is a single document and it will give you "[String:Any]" dictionary object. So simply getting its count is the result you needed.
    let dict = _snapshot.data()
    print(dict.count)
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering. i have uploaded screenshot of my db. HoDYPGk4wvhrlgvA3bRYPAromE22 this id is current user. here current followig three user. how i can count three user of current user following

Comment: how can i migrate REF_FOLLOWING.child(userId).observe(.value, with: {
         snapshot in
                 let count = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
                completion(count)
             }) to firestore

Comment: @PvDev Please check Edit part of answer.

Comment: thanks... it works fine.. i need another help pls. can you check this out question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790875

Comment: @PvDev Same question?

Comment: Hey sry.. can you this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792270/firestore-overwrites-already-exist-data-in-ios-swift