# Firestore overwrites already exist data in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

HoDYPGk4wvhrlgvA3bRYPAromE22 is currently logged in user. In firestore db i have followers and following tables. If current user taps on following button it writes in following table - current user is document id and then following user id with boolean true.

Here is the screenshot of following table.[image]

My issues when user taps on following button it overwrites 6wP1l0yBDDQA146NqNBBzFEgX4u2 following id. it does not add has  new id.

here is the code i tried:

```
 self.db.collection("followers").document(id).setData([API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid: true])
      self.db.collection("following").document(API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).setData([id: true])
```

if give merge: true in after setData like setDfata([id:true], merge: true) it says method overloads argument.

I tried like this but does not too work:

```
     func followAction(withUser id: String) {

    print("withuser:::\(id)")
    let docRef = db.collection("user-posts").document(id)
    print("id::::\(docRef)")

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {

            self.db.collection("followers").document(id).setData([API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid: true])

             self.db.collection("following").document(API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).setData([id: true])

            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")

            self.db.collection("feed").document(API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).setData([document.documentID: true])

        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
            self.db.collection("followers").document(id).updateData([API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid: true])

            self.db.collection("following").document(API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).updateData([id: true])
        }
    }

 //        self.db.collection("followers").document(id).setData([API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid: true])
  //        self.db.collection("following").document(API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).setData([id: true])

  //        self.db.collection("following").document(API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).setData([id: true])
 // REF_FOLLOWERS.child(id).child(Api.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).setValue(true)
 // REF_FOLLOWING.child(Api.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).child(id).setValue(true)

 }
```

Comment: As I told in my previous answer its a Dictionary for a single document so whenever you're writing it is replacing the whole dictionary with new dictionary. You need to use auto generated key, it should be like - `following -> userId -> autoGeneratedKey -> [followingUserId: userId1], autoGeneratedKey -> [followingUserId: userId2]`. Hope you got it. !!

Comment: @TheTiger No actually i suppose to be use only uid not auto generated key

Comment: @TheTiger hey any updates ..

Comment: Then you need to update the whole dictionary not just the new key-value. You have data for `HoDYPGk4wvhrlgvA3bRYPAromE22` user add new data to this dictionary and save.

Comment: Any sample code there for this..

Comment: @TheTiger i have updated my question can you check it out

Comment: PvDev: Check the answer now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I will use Auto incremented key here. `Following -> AutoKey -> ["followedBy": userId1, followedTo: userId2]` because Firestore supports queries by which you can easily filter the users followed by someone. But based on comments and your current DB structure you need to fetch the previous data before updating it else it will replace the old data. See below example:

```
let followingRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Following").document("HoDYPGk4wvhrlgvA3bRYPAromE22")
followingRef.getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
    guard let _snapshot = snapshot else {return}

    if !_snapshot.exists {
        /// First time following someone
        followingRef.setData(["6wP1l0yBDDQA146NqNBBzFEgX4u2": true])
        return
    }

    // For next time
    var data = _snapshot.data()
    data["6wP1l0yBDDQA146NqNBBzFEgX4u2"] = true
    followingRef.setData(data)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering will check and come back to you.

Comment: hey can you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50830295/how-to-get-match-data-and-retrieve-from-firestore-in-ios-swift