# Table view shows duplicate data in iOS Swift using Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift

Here i am using firestore database. I am fetching user table data into table view cell. In table view listing all user with follow button option. If user runs for first time table view does not duplicate data, when user closed app and came back again, goes to people suggestion tab to list all user and its all users are duplicated.

Here is the screen shot: [image]

```
 import UIKit

 class peopleViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var users: [Users] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "People"
    loadUsers()

}



func loadUsers() {


    API.User.observeUser { (user) in
        self.isFollowing(userId: user.id!, completed: { (value) in
            user.isFollowing = value

            self.users.append(user)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })
    }

}


func isFollowing(userId: String, completed: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    API.Follow.isFollowing(userId: userId, completed: completed)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ProfileSegue" {
        let profileVC = segue.destination as! UserViewController
        let userId = sender  as! String
        profileVC.userId = userId
        profileVC.delegate = self as? UserViewControllerDelegate
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return users.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PeopleTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! peopleTableViewCell


    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    print("letuser::::\(user)")
    cell.user = user
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}





 }
  extension peopleViewController: PeopleTableViewCellDelegate {
  func goToProfileUserVC(userId: String) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ProfileSegue", sender: userId)


 }
}
```

Here is the code how fetch data from firestore :

```
     func observeUser(completion: @escaping (Users) -> Void) {

    db.collection("users")
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {

                self.userList.removeAll()

                var user : Users?
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                     user = Users.transformUser(postDictionary: document.data(), key: document.documentID)
    //                        self.userList.append(user!)
                    completion(user!)
                }

    //                    completion(user!)

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is that `Users`?

Answer (score 2):

on func `loadUsers()` before the line `self.users.append(user)` write the line `self.users.removeAll()`

if that's not the problem then you have to remove all the duplicates from the array..

To do that you have to create a func that removes duplicates
e.g.

```
func removeMyDuplicates{
    var newListOfUsers:[User] = []

    for user in self.users{
        var added = false
        for newUser in self.newListOfUsers{
            if(user.id == newUser.id){
                added = true
            }
        }
        if !added{
            newUsers.append(user)
        }
    }
    self.users = newUsers
}
```

And you call the func before reload your table view

Comment: Yep thanks for answering. it works good.. can you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792270/firestore-overwrites-already-exist-data-in-ios-swift

Answer (score 1):

Because you are appending same data to your array. Can you try to clear your array  in **loadUsers** method?

```
   func loadUsers() {

        self.users = []

        API.User.observeUser { (user) in
            self.isFollowing(userId: user.id!, completed: { (value) in
                user.isFollowing = value

                self.users.append(user)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It works fine.. hey can you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790875 pls...

Comment: hey sry not that question . can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792270/firestore-overwrites-already-exist-data-in-ios-swift

Comment: Don't have an idea.

Comment: Hey i did nothing i just added self.users = [] this line. that's it

Comment: Hey can you check my question again since i have updated it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792270/firestore-overwrites-already-exist-data-in-ios-swift. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. in my case sometimes the addSnapshotListener is called 10x times. it's happing because of the Listener storing cache on the system. same as we face issue with notification center observers.

To fix this, we have to get all the previously added listeners and remove them.

```
//Store old listeners in array
var listenerRegistrations: [ListenerRegistration] = []
let listener = db.collection("yourCollection").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
    // Handle snapshot updates or errors here
}
listenerRegistrations.append(listener) 

// Remove all listener registrations
for registration in listenerRegistrations {
    registration.remove()
}
// Clear the array after removing all registrations
listenerRegistrations.removeAll()
```